# collection_select does not reload the item after page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have the following code for collection_select

```
<%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "-Select a Customer"}, :style=>'width:210px;'%><br />
```

Problem :-
If i select a customer and then refresh the page, the collection_select does not refresh the list but shows the previously selected item.
How can i ensure that when i refresh/reload the page even the collection_select gets refreshed? guidance required (sorry for the bad English)

Comment: used it now, it worked. :) Thank you for the answer, is that the only way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is browser specific. Modern browsers can remember your choices upon a soft refresh and pre-select them. Generally a re-submission of the url should be enough to ensure a clean form is displayed.

Ctrl+F5, like Sachin asked you to do, generally removes the browser cache for that particular page before refreshing and hence works as you have seen.

Comment: Thanks a lot Druva This is clears things up. thumbs up for the answer. :)